# Augmented Reality 3D animation on iOS / Android

Tags: android, ios, animation, augmented-reality

I've read through a lot of questions here on SO before asking this one.
We are currently working on an Augmented Reality App for iOS and Android to display some 3D models. We are using the Vuforia framework.

Displaying static objects works great with Vuforia, but we would like to display a 3D model which is animated. We know that this is possible using the Unity framework. 
The problem is that this isn't free and way too expensive for our purpose.

We would like to know if there is another way of displaying animated 3D models?
Maybe using another framework or something?

And if I have an application like Maya or similar, how would I possibly export the animations so I can use these on iPhone.

Thanks so much in advance,

Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used junaio and there you can use md2 models with small animations. Junaio is a free framework. Also I have used osgart(for desktop PCs) and have done skeleton animations using openscenegraph library. I think osgart now has a mobile version and it should support animations. But osgart for mobile  is not free.

In addition metaio and Total immersion libraries also supports animations.

osgart,metaio and TL support even some complex animations

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen some of these before, but I haven't had a closer look at it. Do you know if it is possible to export animations from Maya or Blender? We have some 3D guys that would provide complex animations but it seems that you have to do everything manually. This would be one hell of a task! Thanks in advance

Comment: In junaio and osgart you can't export very complex animations like skeleton animations. But normal animations are supported. In total immersion library some skeleton animations actually supported. In AR its better to keep animation and number of polygons as minimum and simple as possible.